# Jsp to my sql connection error.

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, jdbc

This error please help:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /select.jsp
localhost cannot be resolved

14:     connection = DriverManager.getConnection(localhost, "root", "apurva");
;
```

Comment: put localhost in quotes -> "localhost"

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass database connection url, instead of just `localhost`, like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/`

[here's a good example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)

Comment: Your answer is wrong, @mserioli is right in his comment

Comment: @Leos Please help me understand how my answer is wrong! as per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) `public static Connection getConnection(String url, String user,                        String password)` where `url - a database url of the form jdbc:subprotocol:subname`

Comment: You are right about jdbc, but Apurva has compilation error because he forget to enclose string localhost into double quotes.

Comment: @LeosLiterak your *solution* will make the code able to compile but not to work. This is a right solution. Anyway, a bigger problem is OP writing Java code directly in JSP.

Comment: There is no my solution or answer.